# Chrome Extension Local Storage Values Not Running on Main Page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

So I have set up an options.html page and my new tab page. The options page is fully functional and the values from local storage can be used, saved, and loaded. On my main page I've given it access to the settings.js file that does all of the local storage stuff and it says that all the values are undefined - Is there any way I can get the values from the options page local storage on to my new tab page?

Manifest:

```
{
"background": {
   "persistent": false,
   "scripts": [ "script/background.js" ]
},
"chrome_url_overrides": {
   "newtab": "dashboard.html"
},
"description": "Upgrade Your New Tab to SearchTab",
"icons": {
"16": "images/icons/icon16.jpg",
"48": "images/icons/icon48.jpg",
"128": "images/icons/icon128.jpg"
},
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "SearchTab",
"options_page": "options.html",
"offline_enabled": true,
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",
"permissions": ["unlimitedStorage", "tabs"],
"version": "1.0.0"
}
```

settings.js

```
var defaultSearchPanel = "open";
var defaultBarBackground = "#000000";
var defaultBarColor = "#ffffff";

function loadOptions() {

    var searchPanel = localStorage["searchPanel"];
    var barBackground = localStorage["barBackground"];
    var barColor = localStorage["barColor"];

    if (searchPanel == undefined || (searchPanel != "open" && searchPanel != "closed")) {
        searchPanel = defaultSearchPanel;
    } else if(barBackground == undefined || (barBackground != "#000000" && barBackground != "#ffffff" && barBackground != "#333333" && barBackground != "#006633" && barBackground != "#336699" && barBackground != "#990000" && barBackground != "#CC6600")) {
        barBackground = defaultBarBackground;
    } else if(barColor == undefined || (barColor != "#000000" && barColor != "#ffffff" && barColor != "#333333" && barColor != "#006633" && barColor != "#336699" && barColor != "#990000" && barColor != "#CC6600")) {
        barColor = defaultBarColor;
    }

    var xSearchPanel = document.getElementById("searchPanel");
    var xBarBackground = document.getElementById("barBackground");
    var xBarColor = document.getElementById("barColor");

    for (var i = 0; i < xSearchPanel.children.length; i++) {
        var child = xSearchPanel.children[i];
        if (child.value == searchPanel) {
            child.selected = "true";
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < xBarBackground.children.length; i++) {
        var child = xBarBackground.children[i];
        if (child.value == barBackground) {
            child.selected = "true";
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < xBarColor.children.length; i++) {
        var child = xBarColor.children[i];
        if (child.value == barColor) {
            child.selected = "true";
            break;
        }
    }
}

function saveOptions() {
    var xSearchPanel = document.getElementById("searchPanel");
    var xBarBackground = document.getElementById("barBackground");
    var xBarColor = document.getElementById("barColor");

    var searchPanelDisplay = xSearchPanel.children[xSearchPanel.selectedIndex].value;
    var barBackgroundDisplay = xBarBackground.children[xBarBackground.selectedIndex].value;
    var barColorDisplay = xBarColor.children[xBarColor.selectedIndex].value;

    localStorage["searchPanel"] = searchPanelDisplay;
    localStorage["barBackground"] = barBackgroundDisplay;
    localStorage["barColor"] = barColorDisplay;
    localStorage.setItem('searchPanel', searchPanelDisplay);
    localStorage.setItem('barBackground', barBackgroundDisplay);
    localStorage.setItem('barColor', barColorDisplay);
    alert('Your Settings Have Been Saved');
}

function eraseOptions() {
    localStorage.removeItem("searchPanel");
    location.reload();
}

/* PAGE OPTIONS */
/* OPTIONS */
var searchPanelDisplay = localStorage["searchPanel"];
var searchBarBackground = localStorage["barBackground"];
var searchBarColor = localStorage["barColor"];

if(localStorage["searchPanel"] == 'closed') {
    alert('hello');
} else {
    alert('nope');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The script that is executed in Chrome Extensions is protected by the [CSP (content security policy)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy). In order to read from a different "sandboxed" component's localStorage, you'll have to use [some sort of messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging), and quite possibly a background page to echo the localStorage data between components. What I'd suggest doing is just dealing with the one-time requests, and after you get used to that and feel that you would like to, you could possibly switch over to any of the other methods.